# Can I access to core location api when location service is not allowed?

Tags: core-location

I want to search the current location in my app, but I see entire location service is not allowed.

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager* locationManager;
    CLLocation* currentLocation;
} //header file

//implementation header file
(void)loginButtonPressed:(id)aSender
{
    if (locationManager == nil)
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    }            

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

//implementation CLLocationManagerDelegate
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"update location");
    if(self.currentLocation == nil)
    {
        self.currentLocation = newLocation;
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"fail with error");
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.currentLocation = nil;
}
```

When `locationManager` calls `startUpdatingLocation` (supposing location service is not allowed), `locationManager` cannot get current location and calls the `didFailWithError: method`.
In my case, `locationManager` calls nothing with iOS5 but calls `didFailWithError: method` with iOS4. I don't know what is my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should always check if location monitoring is allowed before starting any location updates. If the user has changed their preference for your app, you will only get the errors instead of actual location updates.

You should check if location updates are available, and if not, notify the user that they need to re-enable location services for your app for it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Before locationManager starts to call startUpdatingLocation method, It must check the status of CLLocationManager. So condition in if statement is changed to like this [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]